# Bootstrap grid - div next to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the second div.
 My code actually looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid section" style="height: 100%; background:#F7E999;" id="offer">
   <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
         <div class="col">
            <h1 class="text-light">Oferta</h1>
            <div class="col-md-12"><img src="./image/image1.png" style="width:30%">Lorem ipsum...</div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><img src="./image/image2.png" style="width:30%">Lorem ipsum...</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make a table from divs which has two columns and two rows? I need the Image and first "Lorem ipsum..." in one row and two cols, and same with next two.

I tried to do it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12>
<div class="col-md-6></div>
<div class="col-md-6></div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 10):

You must wrap your columns in a row.

Change this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assuming your outermost `col-md-12` is also within a `row`.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer to confirm it solved your problem.